# What is a good way to filter using 2 columns.grouping on a 3rd field

Tags: mysql, sql, join, where-clause, mysql-workbench

I have a mysql table that looks like the following:

```
ID  GROUP   FILTER1     FILTER2
--  --      --------    --------
1   27      22337755    NULL
2   28      22337755    NULL
3   22      22337755    22337744
4   4       22337635    22337635
5   4       22337755    22337755
6   4       22337635    22337744
```

I'd like to filter out any IDs that match a filter.  My first pass looked like:

```
SELECT ID FROM mytable
WHERE
(FILTER1 <> '22337755')
AND
((FILTER2 <> '22337755') OR (FILTER2 IS NULL))
```

This query is close but the query doesn't take into account the GROUP column and since the very last row #6 doesn't contain 22337755 in either column so it gets returned even though #5 should take it out of the list.

What is a good way to remove rows that had a FILTER hit on any row in the group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you have plus:

```
AND [GROUP] NOT IN 
(SELECT [GROUP] FROM mytable WHERE FILTER1 = '22337755' OR FILTER2 = '22337755')
```